# How to upload particular video file format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload

I need to upload video files. I am using `<input type="file">`. But it accepts all types of files.I need only files with extensions such as `.vlc and .mp4` . How can I make the upload dialogue to select only these videos file format.
And also I am trying like below:

```
<input type="file" accept=".vlc">
```

But its not working.
I found below in the google search:

```
<p>Only show .WAV files...</p>
<input type="file" accept=".vlc" ID="fileSelect" runat="server" />
```

But this is asp.net code, How do I use it in ruby on rails for run this control on server side

Kindly suggest me waiting for reply
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whitelisting at this point doesn't make sense. Let the user choose whatever he likes and validate in the backend. If still needed try to go with somthing like [this](http://jqueryvalidation.org/accept-method/), a jquery mime type validation plugin.

When using [carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave) for uploading you should use the provided whitelist feature. Take a look here:
https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#securing-uploads

[Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) comes with a set of validation helpers for dealing with such restrictions:
http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/Validators/HelperMethods

As always this depends on your setup. In most cases you should be good to go with one of these gems to make your live easier.

Comment: But I am not using `carrierwave` and `paperclip` I simple use html tag for file uploade `<input type='File'>`

Comment: So why do you tag your question with 'ruby on rails'? validating such things in the front end is always a bad idea. But I edited my post and pointed to a jquery plugin for such a purpose.